# Simple Graph chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying the following code:

```
function makeGraph() {
      var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("monotone")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

      // Add the line path.
      svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line(data));
    }
```

where

```
data = [
         {"date": "2014-08-04","value": 1000},
         {"date": "2014-08-05","value": 1110}
       ]
```

However, I'm getting this error:
Error: Problem parsing `d="MNaN,70CNaN,70,NaN,31.5,NaN,31.5SNaN,87.49999999999994,NaN,87.49999999999994SNaN,139...`

Perhaps I need to parse the dates to represent points..but not sure how to do it.

Comment: What's your `x` scale? Most likely you didn't parse the dates.

Comment: My xScale is date : var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

Lesson learnt: Always parse the data before using it, if it contains date.
Something like this:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
});
```